# ¿Cómo llamar a las funciones desde main?

Tags: c++

¿Cómo visualizar los datos que ingreso en una clase en *C++*?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
class cparticipante{
    private:
        char *nombre;
        char *apellido;
        char sexo; //masculino o femenino
        char *lugar_nacimiento; //ciudad y pais
        char *pais_residencia;
        char *doc_identidad; //cedula,carnet, pasaporte
        char *telefono; // (505)3114012
        char *e_mail;
    public:
        cparticipante();
        cparticipante(char *,char *,char,char *,char *,char *,char *,char *);
        ~cparticipante();
        cparticipante(const cparticipante &);
        cparticipante &operator=(const cparticipante &);
        void setparticipante(char *,char *,char,char *,char *,char *,char *,char *);
        void getparticipante(char *,char *,char *,char *,char *,char *,char *,char *)const;
        };
cparticipante::cparticipante(){

}

cparticipante::cparticipante(char *,char *,char,char *,char *,char *,char *,char *){

}




main(){
        class cparticipante cp; 
        int op;
            do{     
            cout<<"1. Introducir participante"<<endl;
            cout<<"2. Mostrar participante"<<endl;
            cout<<"3. Crear una copia del participante"<<endl;
            cout<<"4. Asignar un participante en otro"<<endl;
            cout<<"5. Salir"<<endl;
            cout<<"Elija una opcion"<<endl;
            cin>>op;
            switch(op){
                case 1:                 
                    break;
                case 2:
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                case 4:
                    break;
                case 5:
                    break;
                default:
                    cout<<"Opcion invalida"<<endl;
            }
            system("cls");
        }while(op!=5);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para imprimir valores en consola puedes usar a salida estándar con la instrucción `cout` perteneciente al `namespace std`.

> Este es un ejemplo de cómo podrías utilizarlo en tu código:
>
> ```
> ...
> using namepace std;
> class cparticipante
> { 
>     private: 
>         char* nombre;
>         ...
>
>      public:
>          // Declaras al método miembro.
>          const void imprimirInfo();
> }
>
> // Defines el método miembro.  
> const void   cparticipante::imprimirInfo()
> {
>     cout << "El nombre del participante es: " << this.nombre << " /n";
>     // El anterior es un ejemplo para imprimir el atributo nombre, debes repetirlo con cada atributo a mostrar de la clase.
>     ...
> }
>
> public int main()
> {
>     ...
>     // Instancias primero un objeto de la clase cparticipante.
>     cparticipante part = ...;
>     // Luego llamas al método imprimirInfo de la clase cparticipante.
>     part.imprimirInfo();
>     ...
>  }
> ```

De esta manera definir la función que imprima el valor de cada atributo que desees imprimir de cada instancia de `cparticipante`.

Los atributos de tu clase `cparticipante`  los has declarado como privados, es decir, que solo podrá acceder a leerlos o modificarlos la misma clase que los contiene. Debido a que así están definidos los atributos, la única manera de acceder a ellos es por medio de funciones miembro de la clase, de esta manera que controlas y restringes el acceso a los miembros privados de `cparticipante` a las demás clases.

En esta [página](http://dis.unal.edu.co/~fgonza/courses/2003/poo/c++.htm) tocan este tema que tiene que ver con tu pregunta, en el explican lo siguiente:

> Las variables de miembro son declaradas privadas para que funciones de
>   miembro de otras funciones no tengan acceso a ellas sino a travez de
>   la correspondiente funcion Get o Set. Las funciones de miembro si son
>   declaradas públicas de tal modo que se pueda acceder a ellas desde
>   otras funciones.

Lo explicado anteriormente indica que debes crear funciones para leer o cambiar los valores de tus atributos privados de clase. Las funciones que sólo obtienen los valores se conocen como `Getters` y las que les alteran el valor como `Setters` y se acostumbran a programar para cada miembro privado de la clase según lo que quieras permitir, si leer, cambiar o ambas.

> ### Por ejemplo:
>
> Este es un ejemplo de `Getter` en tu clase `cparticipante`:
>
> ```
> ...
> class cparticipante
> { 
>     private: 
>         char *nombre;
>         ...
>
>      public:
>          // De esta manera defines un Getter para el atributo nombre.
>          const char* getNombre() { return nombre; }
> }
> ```
>
> Y este un ejemplo de `Setter` en tu clase `cparticipante`:
>
> ```
> ...
> class cparticipante
> { 
>     private: 
>         char *nombre;
>         ...
>
>      public:
>          // De esta manera defines un Setter para el atributo nombre.
>          char* setNombre(char* Nombre) { nombre = Nombre; }
> }
> ```

De esta manera ya podrías obtener o modificar el valor de los atributos de una instancia de la clase `cparticipante`.

Si utilizas lo anterior podrás imprimir la información de la siguiente manera:

> ```
> public int main()
> {
>     ...
>     // Primero instancias un objeto de la clase cparticipante .
>     cparticipante part = ...;
> ```
>
> .        // Luego llamas al método getNombre de la clase cparticipante.
>           cout << "El nombre del participante es:" << part.getNombre() << "/n";
>           ...
>        }

Answer (score 2):

Dado que todas las variables miembro son privadas:

```
class cparticipante{
    private:
        char *nombre;
        char *apellido;
        char sexo; //masculino o femenino
        char *lugar_nacimiento; //ciudad y pais
        char *pais_residencia;
        char *doc_identidad; //cedula,carnet, pasaporte
        char *telefono; // (505)3114012
        char *e_mail;
```

Lo esperado sería que la clase disponga de una función *get* para cada variable:

```
    class cparticipante
    {
      public:
        const char* Nombre() const
        { retur nombre; }

        // ...
    };
```